# Getting the same tensor for "prob" and "class" in FastAI TabularLearner

Tags: python, kaggle, fast-ai

I am very new to FastAI. I just finished the first lesson of the fastai course here: https://course.fast.ai/ and am implementing a Tabular Learner on the "Machine Learning From Disaster" Titanic Dataset on kaggle. Here is my code:

```py
from fastcore.all import *
from fastai.tabular.all import *
df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/titanic/train.csv')

# only keeping relevant variables
df = df[['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare']]

# categorical and continuous variables
cat_names = ['Sex', 'Pclass']
cont_names = ['Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare']

I am not sure exactly what these do but they were in the example code and seem to be necessary
procs = [Categorify, FillMissing, Normalize]

dls = TabularDataLoaders.from_df(df, procs=procs, cat_names=cat_names, cont_names=cont_names, y_names="Survived", bs=64)

learner = tabular_learner(dls)
learner.fit(50)

# prediction sample, dropping the target column before inputting to the model
sample = df.iloc[0]
sample = sample.drop(['Survived'])

row, clas, prob = learner.predict(sample)
```

printing row gives me the correct row

```
   Sex  Pclass  Age_na       Age     SibSp     Parch     Fare  Survived
0  1.0     3.0     1.0 -1.983648  0.401285  0.751157 -0.32982  0.711407
```

But when I print 'clas' and 'prob' I get the same tensor, when really 'clas' should return the index of the desired output (0 or 1)

```
clas: tensor([0.7114])
prob: tensor([0.7114])
```

I have two questions:

- Why could this be happening?
- What is `procs` and why is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

`procs` is a list of `TabularProc`edures. These are transforms that are applied to your data when it becomes available. For instance, `FillMissing` will fill any missing column values with some value (by default, the median of the available column values). Some of the transforms (like `FillMissing`) are necessary to keep your data well-formed, while others like `Normalize` may not be strictly necessary but are likely to help your model converge faster.

I don't know why `clas` isn't behaving as expected. The docs agree with your expectation and I checked with code similar to yours and had the same result you did.